# Avoid Page refresh

Tags: asp.net

Hi I'm using the two RadDateTimePickers for start and enddates in my asp.net application.
I'm implemeting the selecteddatechanged events.
Because If both dates selected I will enable button.

Whenever I selected the date every time page is refreshing.
So I'm loosing the previous. result.
I have placed the whole code in asp updatepanel but page result is not showing.
How can I solve this?

Comment: How and where can mark my questions are answered?

Comment: did you follow and read the link I placed in the previous comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the AutoPostBackControl property  to see if you are posting back.

It looks like you are trying to use a server side event.

I don't fully understand your scenario but It looks like you would be better served using a client-side event.  RadDateTimePicker has OnDateSelected.  On the most recent version of RadControls

```
 ClientEvents-OnDateSelected
```

you could then have both pickers run javascript to check if both pickers have a selected date.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function StartPicker_DateSelected(s, e) {
        checkDates();
    }

    function EndPicker_DateSelected(s, e) {
        checkDates();
    }

    function checkDates() {
        var start = $find('<%= startPicker.ClientID %>').get_selectedDate();
        var end = $find('<%= endPicker.ClientID %>').get_selectedDate();

        if (start && end) {
            //enable Button
            alert('button enabled');
        }

    }
</script>

    <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="startPicker" runat="server" ClientEvents-OnDateSelected="StartPicker_DateSelected">
    </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
    <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="endPicker" runat="server" ClientEvents-OnDateSelected="EndPicker_DateSelected">
    </telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
```

Comment: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>). 
I'm getting the above errormessage

Comment: Where do you have the script tag placed?

Comment: Yes first I placed in heas tag but late I moved to body so its working.

Comment: How Cloud I accept ur answer as answer here? Here I clound not found any link or button to accept answer as answer

Comment: There should be a white checkbox to the left of my answer.  You click that to toggle answer.  If .you read the link I posted in the comment to your question it explains more.

Comment: Ya. thanks. I have small doubt. I have asp:imageButton in my asp:table. I'm trying to access the id of that button as document.getElementByid('btn') but I'm unable to get it why?

Comment: Can you post this as a new question.